# Problem with python cec in raspbian stretch

Tags: hdmi, raspbian-stretch, python-2.x, cec-client

I have rpi 1 model b with stretch installed. I want to use python cec library.
First I tried to install it.

```
sudo apt install python-libcec
```

But fails to import cec ::

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170124] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cec/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _cec = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cec/__init__.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_cec')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _cec
```

Then I tried to install by pip :: `sudo apt install python-pip  libcec4-dev`

But `sudo pip install cec`  fails with this error ::

```
Collecting cec
  Using cached cec-0.2.5.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: cec
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cec ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-fXgVtd/cec/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpdR4oC1pip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'cec' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-armv6l-2.7
  arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-9xgeTe/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c cec.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv6l-2.7/cec.o
  cec.cpp: In function ‘std::__cxx11::list<CEC::cec_adapter> get_adapters()’:
  cec.cpp:102:27: error: ‘class CEC::ICECAdapter’ has no member named ‘FindAdapters’; did you mean ‘PingAdapter’?
   #define CEC_FIND_ADAPTERS FindAdapters
                             ^
  cec.cpp:153:29: note: in expansion of macro ‘CEC_FIND_ADAPTERS’
      int count = CEC_adapter->CEC_FIND_ADAPTERS(dev_list, cec_count);
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cec.cpp:102:27: error: ‘class CEC::ICECAdapter’ has no member named ‘FindAdapters’; did you mean ‘PingAdapter’?
   #define CEC_FIND_ADAPTERS FindAdapters
                             ^
  cec.cpp:158:28: note: in expansion of macro ‘CEC_FIND_ADAPTERS’
         count = CEC_adapter->CEC_FIND_ADAPTERS(dev_list, cec_count);
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cec.cpp: In function ‘void initcec()’:
  cec.cpp:657:19: error: ‘CEC::ICECCallbacks {aka struct CEC::ICECCallbacks}’ has no member named ‘CBCecLogMessage’; did you mean ‘logMessage’?
      CEC_callbacks->CBCecLogMessage = log_cb;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cec.cpp:658:19: error: ‘CEC::ICECCallbacks {aka struct CEC::ICECCallbacks}’ has no member named ‘CBCecKeyPress’; did you mean ‘keyPress’?
      CEC_callbacks->CBCecKeyPress = keypress_cb;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cec.cpp:659:19: error: ‘CEC::ICECCallbacks {aka struct CEC::ICECCallbacks}’ has no member named ‘CBCecCommand’
      CEC_callbacks->CBCecCommand = command_cb;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  cec.cpp:660:19: error: ‘CEC::ICECCallbacks {aka struct CEC::ICECCallbacks}’ has no member named ‘CBCecConfigurationChanged’; did you mean ‘configurationChanged’?
      CEC_callbacks->CBCecConfigurationChanged = config_cb;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cec.cpp:661:19: error: ‘CEC::ICECCallbacks {aka struct CEC::ICECCallbacks}’ has no member named ‘CBCecAlert’
      CEC_callbacks->CBCecAlert = alert_cb;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~
  cec.cpp:662:19: error: ‘CEC::ICECCallbacks {aka struct CEC::ICECCallbacks}’ has no member named ‘CBCecMenuStateChanged’; did you mean ‘menuStateChanged’?
      CEC_callbacks->CBCecMenuStateChanged = menu_cb;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cec.cpp:663:19: error: ‘CEC::ICECCallbacks {aka struct CEC::ICECCallbacks}’ has no member named ‘CBCecSourceActivated’; did you mean ‘sourceActivated’?
      CEC_callbacks->CBCecSourceActivated = activated_cb;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cec
  Running setup.py clean for cec
Failed to build cec
Installing collected packages: cec
  Running setup.py install for cec ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-fXgVtd/cec/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qPO7Pl-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'cec' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-armv6l-2.7
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-9xgeTe/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c cec.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv6l-2.7/cec.o
    cec.cpp: In function ‘std::__cxx11::list<CEC::cec_adapter> get_adapters()’:
    cec.cpp:102:27: error: ‘class CEC::ICECAdapter’ has no member named ‘FindAdapters’; did you mean ‘PingAdapter’?
     #define CEC_FIND_ADAPTERS FindAdapters
                               ^
    cec.cpp:153:29: note: in expansion of macro ‘CEC_FIND_ADAPTERS’
        int count = CEC_adapter->CEC_FIND_ADAPTERS(dev_list, cec_count);
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    cec.cpp:102:27: error: ‘class CEC::ICECAdapter’ has no member named ‘FindAdapters’; did you mean ‘PingAdapter’?
     #define CEC_FIND_ADAPTERS FindAdapters
                               ^
    cec.cpp:158:28: note: in expansion of macro ‘CEC_FIND_ADAPTERS’
           count = CEC_adapter->CEC_FIND_ADAPTERS(dev_list, cec_count);
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    cec.cpp: In function ‘void initcec()’:
    cec.cpp:657:19: error: ‘CEC::ICECCallbacks {aka struct CEC::ICECCallbacks}’ has no member named ‘CBCecLogMessage’; did you mean ‘logMessage’?
        CEC_callbacks->CBCecLogMessage = log_cb;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    cec.cpp:658:19: error: ‘CEC::ICECCallbacks {aka struct CEC::ICECCallbacks}’ has no member named ‘CBCecKeyPress’; did you mean ‘keyPress’?
        CEC_callbacks->CBCecKeyPress = keypress_cb;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    cec.cpp:659:19: error: ‘CEC::ICECCallbacks {aka struct CEC::ICECCallbacks}’ has no member named ‘CBCecCommand’
        CEC_callbacks->CBCecCommand = command_cb;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    cec.cpp:660:19: error: ‘CEC::ICECCallbacks {aka struct CEC::ICECCallbacks}’ has no member named ‘CBCecConfigurationChanged’; did you mean ‘configurationChanged’?
        CEC_callbacks->CBCecConfigurationChanged = config_cb;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    cec.cpp:661:19: error: ‘CEC::ICECCallbacks {aka struct CEC::ICECCallbacks}’ has no member named ‘CBCecAlert’
        CEC_callbacks->CBCecAlert = alert_cb;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~
    cec.cpp:662:19: error: ‘CEC::ICECCallbacks {aka struct CEC::ICECCallbacks}’ has no member named ‘CBCecMenuStateChanged’; did you mean ‘menuStateChanged’?
        CEC_callbacks->CBCecMenuStateChanged = menu_cb;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    cec.cpp:663:19: error: ‘CEC::ICECCallbacks {aka struct CEC::ICECCallbacks}’ has no member named ‘CBCecSourceActivated’; did you mean ‘sourceActivated’?
        CEC_callbacks->CBCecSourceActivated = activated_cb;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-fXgVtd/cec/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qPO7Pl-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-fXgVtd/cec/
```

Answer (score 1):

Refering to [this](https://github.com/trainman419/python-cec) and I would simply do:

```
wget http://packages.namniart.com/repos/namniart.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.namniart.com/repos/pi wheezy main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libcec.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-dev build-essential libcec-dev cec-utils
```

and then finally install with `pip`:

```
pip install cec
```

Should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately library provided in stretch release of raspbian also looks like faulty. The package for regular Debian release contains additional file _cec.{architecture_name}.so, which would normally be loaded. This file is missing in rpi, thus "ImportError: No module named _cec" is shown.

I think we need to compile this library from source as described here:
https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec/blob/master/docs/README.raspberrypi.md

PS: the other answer suggests to install library with similar name but this pycec library (https://github.com/trainman419/python-cec) is just a wrapper around libcec. libcec contains its own python bindings (https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec) and these are these bindings that are not working for OP.